BIBO stable LTI systems
I have a previous exam question that I am having issues understanding.
So the question is, which of the following LTI systems are BIBO stable?
$$h_1(t)=e^{-t}u(t+5)$$
$$h_2(t)=sin(3t)u(t)$$
$$h_3(t)=u(t)$$
$$h_4(t)=\frac{1}{t^2}u(t)$$
Where $u(t)$ is a step function and $h(t)$ is the impulse response
I can reason my way to say that $h_1$ is stable, but the answer sheet claims that both $h_1$ and $h_4$ is stable.
So the question is how is $h_4$ stable?
Doesn't the integral explode at $t=0$ causing it to be unstable?

You are right in my opinion. The criterion is absolute integrability, which I agree with you, is not satisfied for $h_{4}$. Some texts simply say that impulse response should go to $0$ as $t \to \infty$, which is satisfied. Check what the book says is the criterion.
